# How to remove mullvad Vpn on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, uninstall

I tried `sudo apt-get remove Mullvad` It show me this message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6zHJ.png

Comment: Did you install such a package before?

Comment: Also, did you try [this](https://mullvad.net/en/help/install-mullvad-app-linux/)?

Comment: @Sebastian I don't remember. I think  i installed package and then removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Install Mullvad app on Linux](https://mullvad.net/en/help/install-mullvad-app-linux/) run the following command to uninstall the Mullvad app.

```
sudo apt-get purge mullvad-vpn
```

Comment: Thanks, that's worked.